# What is the strtok_s equivalent in VC7?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The strtok_s function exists in vc8 but not in vc7. So what's a function (or code) that does  the equivalent of strtok_s in vc7?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you mean "Where is the strtok_s in VC7" or "What does strtok_s do?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3(VS.80).aspx).

As far as I can tell, the security enhancements a) Make [strtok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(VS.80).aspx)() reentrant (and thread-safe) by having it take a "context" parameter and b) Make it safe to use with NULL pointers. (The actual behaviors in the case of NULL parameters are listed in a table on the page I've linked.)

As for a VC7 alternative, you'll have to write (or import) one yourself. The NULL-safety is easy to do externally, you'll just have to be careful not to pass NULL strings where none are expected; but as far as reentrancy goes, there's no way for strtok() to handle that.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206014/is-there-a-tokenizer-strtok-replacement-function-somewhere-in-cstl-closed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206014/is-there-a-tokenizer-strtok-replacement-function-somewhere-in-cstl-closed) question. I believe POSIX also supplies a reentrant version of strtok() called strtok_r(); you can search for it. It would also be a good (and short) exercise to write an implementation yourself. Shouldn't take more than ~10 lines of code.

Comment: yeah, I'd updated my answer to include more info about strtok() in general, but lost the edit in a freak Firefox accident. The question asks about strtok_s() anyway.